# Node.js- get StringSet from AWS DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to compare string sent from andoid app with string in my DynamoDB stored in StringSet. I tried that code:

```
if (typeof event.keyWord != "undefined") { 

                var str = event.keyWord;
                str = str.toLowerCase();
                params.ExpressionAttributeValues[":keyWord"] = {"S": str};

                params.FilterExpression = params.FilterExpression + " and contains (#nm, :keyWord)";
            }
```

The problem is that in case of StringSet it looks for perfect match. I want to check if the keyWord is part of the second string in the StrinSet #nm. This is my whole code if needed:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var db = new AWS.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {


    var params = {
        TableName: "Events", //"StreamsLambdaTable",
        ProjectionExpression: "ID, description, endDate, imagePath, locationLat, locationLon, #nm",  
        FilterExpression: "locationLon between :lower_lon and :higher_lon and locationLat between :lower_lat and :higher_lat",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#nm": "name",
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
             ":lower_lon": {"N": event.low_lon},
             ":higher_lon": {"N": event.high_lon}, 
             ":lower_lat": {"N": event.low_lat},
             ":higher_lat": {"N": event.high_lat}
        }
    };


     if (typeof event.keyWord != "undefined") { 

                var str = event.keyWord;
                str = str.toLowerCase();
                params.ExpressionAttributeValues[":keyWord"] = {"S": str};

                params.FilterExpression = params.FilterExpression + " and contains (#nm, :keyWord)";
            }


  db.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err); // an error occurred
      } 
    else {

        data.Items.forEach(function(record) {
            console.log(
                record.name.SS + "");
        });


        context.succeed(data.Items); // data.Items


      }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are going to be able to do this with DynamoDB alone. I would look into [integrating DynamoDB with ElasticSearch](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/08/amazon-dynamodb-elasticsearch-integration/) in order to provide this sort of text search capabilities.